# Query posts by a type and another type only if post is in specific category

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, get-posts

I have a featured post type and a reviews post type. I would like to include reviews of a certain category (I use categories from the posts type) as well. How could query args be crafted?

A crude example:

```
get_posts(array('post_type' => array('featured-posts', array('review-posts', 'featured-category'))
```

Need to fetch all the posts in the featured-posts type, also all the posts in the review-posts type if the assigned category is feature-category.

UPDATE: Ended up not needing to implement this but I think Stephen S had the best guess.

Comment: Can you explain it little bit more to understand your problem. It will help you and this community also.

Comment: Updated for a more specific description. I try to be as general as I can but still making sense. It's tough to find search results when questions are so specific to the scope of the asker's issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, but I think you'd need to do two separate queries and merge them together:

```
$args = array(
 'post_type' => 'featured-posts'
);
$featured_posts = get_posts($args);

$args = array(
 'post_type' => 'review-posts',
 'category_name' => 'featured-category'
);
$review_posts = get_posts($args);

$result = array_merge($featured_posts->posts, $review_posts->posts);

$final_query = WP_Query($result);
```

Comment: Didn't end up needing to do this query but your's makes the most sense.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing a query on both post types and including the category? I suspect that it will look only for posts in the featured category, then limit by the two post types, but nonetheless it's worth a try.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'featured-posts', 'review-posts' ),
    'category_name' => 'featured-category'
);
$res_posts = get_posts($args);
```

You can always try playing with [taxonomy parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) (`tax_query`) as well.

Comment: I did try that at first and your assumption was correct. I opted to not use taxonomies with the post types as I wanted to use the main post type categories.